# Why is VS2015 giving me Code Analysis errors when VS2013 was perfectly happy?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-analysis

I have just opened an existing project in VS2015, and while it all built happily in VS2013, I am now getting errors such as CS3002 'Return type is not CLS-compliant' in VS2015.

I have checked the project properties and 'Enable Code Analysis on Build' is unchecked, and looked through the changes in VS2015 but I can't for the life of me see any reason why these errors are now appearing. Has anything changed in Visual Studio?

Comment: Are the errors false positive?

Comment: No. The errors are valid, but a lot of them are code analysis issues I don't really care about. VS2013 seemed to be able to ignore them, but VS2015 seems to complain.

Comment: Different versions of the compiler may throw different warnings / error.

Comment: Code analysis is now integrated in the build.  Called "Live Code Analysis", a Roslyn feature.  Open the References node of the project and note the new "Analyzers" node.  Right-click + Open Active Rule Set to configure it.

Comment: Is there any way of disabling the "Live Code Analysis"? Or would I have to specify an empty RuleSet? It seems odd that they still have the old static Code Analysis stuff as well.

Comment: @ChrisPatrick: Did you find out anything regarding this? I am struggling with the same problem.

Comment: @davenewza - No, so far it seems like the only way to do it is to either use a custom rule set in the Live Code Analysis option (but this is per-project) or to manually ignore the errors in the code.

Comment: @ChrisPatrick: Pity.  This was a important part of our builds.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a simple workaround to this issue. I used suppress to disable the code analysis in my classes above the namespace.

```
#pragma warning disable
```

This won't be a permanent solution. May be it will be useful for someone as of now.